# Merging [sqlalchemy-postgres] into [sqlalchemy]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlalchemy) is an orm for Python.  It works with many databases including SQLite, PostgreSQL and MySQL.  However, the only one of these to get their own tag is [sqlalchemy-postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlalchemy-postgres).

I don't believe that this tag is necessary, as **the standard practice in the `sqlalchemy` tag is to just add a database tag as well** (such as [postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql)) if the question is also database specific.  Additionally, many of the questions are already tagged with `postgresql` and `sqlalchemy` separately, making `postgresql-sqlalchemy` redundant.

I will retag if there's no major negative response here, and wanted to provide an explanation about why these will be bumped to the front.  The majority of these questions are unanswered anyway and seem useful; they may benefit from the extra attention.

Comment: Why not make it a synonym instead?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Because it is not a synonym.  `sqlalchemy-postgres` implies `sqlalchemy` and `postgres` when used correctly (maybe 2 of the questions really require postgres).  Would that also mean there should be a synonym for every other `sqlalchemy-<database>`?  In my opinion, that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I edited all questions tagged `sqlalchemy-postgres`, removing that tag and making sure the question was tagged at least `python` and `sqlalchemy`, as well as `postgresql` where appropriate.  For reference, the following questions were edited:

- [How to create in SQLAlchemy model row with random string when Postgresql is under?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20128502)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/21613076
- [handling LargeBinary data in sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22710045)
- [SqlAlchemy: Querying the length json field having an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23060259)
- [Convert SqlAlchemy orm result to dict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23554119)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/23610608
- [error 'function sum(character varying) does not exist' using sum with SQL Alchemy and Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24134266)
- [SQLAlchemy Core: Creating a last_value window function for postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24470069)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/24485774
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/24682540